# How to get submodule names of a module in the Omnet++ and the Inet

Tags: omnet++, inet

How to get submodule names of a module in the Omnet++ and the Inet by C++ code?

In addition to the above question, it would be nice to know how to get the names of the submodules in a tree view with their relationships to each other?

Thanks

Comment: Could you precise how you want to present tree view and relations - as a text or as an own structure?

Comment: Either mode is fine but structured is preferred.

Comment: Could you show an example of C++ structure (i.e. definition) that should be filled by tree of submodules?

Answer (score 1):

To get the names of all submodules one may use `getSubmoduleNames()`. According to [OMNeT++ Simulation Library](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cModule.html#a95f8267c78650da16f88a168b2b44d6e) it:

> Returns the names of the module's submodules and submodule vectors, including zero-size submodule vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The [API documentation](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cModule.html) helps you. You almost figured out in the question. The submodule names can be returned by the `getSubmoduleNames()` method if the `cModule` class. You can combine that with `getSubmodule()` and other related methods to implement a full tree walk.

Comment: Have you a full code to traverse all submodules a module in different levels?